# Writing a register page for Windows Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am working in a solution with Federation and I am using the Microsoft Azure Cloud. 
From what I understand in Azure we have a page to login but there is no registration page. This means that if I want to expose my portal to the outside world (not just a corporate company) I will have to write my own registration page.
For this, I want to log some data every time someone registers. Is this not dangerous? 
What are the best practices, i.e. what data should I log?

As an administrator of the WAAD, I want to lock/unlock users, is this possible in Azure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you need to use the WAAD Graph API to achieve this:

[See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667022/how-to-add-users-to-azure-active-directory-with-graph-api?rq=1)